# PHP: Custom Framework or Existing Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I work at a company where we are constantly building out sites that require forms. We do the standard operations on these forms such as validation, saving to a DB and etc. These sites typically have an authentication page and then several content pages with forms in between. Should I write my own framework to get this done or is there an existing framework that I should use. My focus here is to lower the amount of repeated coding and or possibly come up with some starting template that most sites can be based off. I'd like this to be an MVC solution and OOP if possible. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Im only voting to close because this doesnt have a real answer. Suggestions are subjective, and its not clear what exact features youre after and what priority they are. Now if you posted can concrete specific requirements Id be willing to post frameworks Ive used that meet those requirements, e.g. sever side form validation, OOP/MVC, routing, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Simply choose from one of the following:-)

```
Adroit
Adventure PHP Framework 
Agavi 
Akelos Framework 
Ambivalence
Amhulio
Andromeda Project
ash.MVC
Atomik Framework
ATK Framework 
Bedrock Framework
Blue Shoes Framework
CakePHP 
Castle-PHP
CIEXtended
CodeIgniter Framework 
CoughPHP 
DIY MVC
DooPHP
DragonPHP
evoCore 
eZ components 
FAT-FREE PHP
Flow3
Flourish
FuelPHP
FUSE MVC Framework 
Fusebox Framework 
Horde Application Framework 
InterJinn 
Ister
Jelix 
KISSMVC
Kimura Framework 
KohanaPHP 
Kolibri 
Konstrukt 
KumbiaPHP
Laravel
LightVC 
LightMVC
Limb3 
Lion framework
Lisa framework 
Lithium
Madeam PHP Framework 
Maintainable PHP Framework 
MagicPHP
Maverick PHP
mgframework
MiMVic
Noloh
NettePHP
Ocubed
Odin Assemble
Open Delight
OpenBiz 
Orinoco
P4A 
Php BURN
PHPCliFramework
PHP on TRAX 
PHPDevShell 
phpHtmlLib
PHOCOA 
PhpPeanuts 
PHPulse 
PHPWork
Pluf 
Prado Framework 
PSX Framework
Qcodo 
QCubed 
QPHP 
Recess!
Sapphire 
Seagull Framework 
SENCHA
Simplicity
SimplePHP
SOLAR Framework 
Sonic Framework
Sourdough
Spaghetti PHP
SpotLight
Stubbles 
Swat 
Symfony 
Tangra Framework 
Tigermouse 
TinyMVC 
TKSelf
VLC for PHP
Vork Enterprise PHP Framework
WACT
WasP
WEB2BB
Xajax 
Xataface 
Yii PHP Framework 
Yellow Duck Framework
Zephyr Framework
Zend Framework 
ZOOP Framework
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all... Why are they better than a custom framework?

Answer (score 2):

First take a look at existing web frameworks, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. If none fits then try to write your own framework. Often custom frameworks are built upon existing ones, but sometimes the needs are so sophisticated they require a solution built from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommed [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) enough. It is easily one of the gratest frameworks out there. The community is just great, the syntax is razor clean. Also the Artisan CLI is great.

Give it try, yo won't regret.